# argument type mismatch in mbeanServer.invoke

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-security, jmx

Ok, so.  I've got a war deployed with an MBean exposed through spring's MBeanExporter and annotations.  I have another war app deployed which is using some code to talk to the mbean.  I'm having an issue calling the function on the mbean from that client code.

RuntimeException occurred in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation getPermissions.

The signature of the mbean method is Collection getPermissions(GrantedAuthority role).

and the code I'm using to call it is

```
Object[] params = {role}; //role is passed in as a GrantedAuthorityImpl (implements GrantedAuthority)
String[] signature = {"org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthority"};

mbeanServer.invoke(new ObjectName(mbeanName), "getPermissions", params, signature);
```

What could be the issue, or what should I look at?

```
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: RuntimeException occurred in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation getPermissions
 javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1080)
 javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:955)
 org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.invoke(SpringModelMBean.java:90)
 org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
 org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBeanInvoker.invoke(RequiredModelMBeanInvoker.java:127)
 org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
 xxx.MBeanPermissionMapLookup.getPermissions(MBeanPermissionMapLookup.java:31)
 xxx.MBeanPermissionMapLookup$$FastClassByCGLIB$$667f3fad.invoke(<generated>) ...


root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
    javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1074)
    javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:955)
    org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.invoke(SpringModelMBean.java:90)
    org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBeanInvoker.invoke(RequiredModelMBeanInvoker.java:127)
    org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    xxx.MBeanPermissionMapLookup.getPermissions(MBeanPermissionMapLookup.java:31)
```

Using Spring 3.0.4, Spring security 3.0.3, jboss 5.1.0, java jdk 1.6.0-17.

Comment: RuntimeException isn't telling you much, typical isn't it! ;).  Are you able to set a debug point?

Comment: yes, and if I change the arguments on both sides to string, it successfully calls the method and returns just fine, I thought it had something to do with the specific spring security class, so I've played around with that but no luck so far.

Comment: Shot in the dark (as I'm not sure how Spring handles this, nor do you show it in your code), but is `role` defined as `GrantedAuthority` or `GrantedAuthorityImpl`?  Spring might not be checking deeply enough to tell that they're interchangeable.

Comment: yea, I've considered that, but I'll try it again... I tried passing it around as a GrantedAuthorityImpl too and creating a new method on the mbean to handle it.  I'm just wondering if I'm missing something conceptually to make this work?  Maybe classloader issues?

Comment: Classloader issues would give you a NoDefFound or ClassNotFound exception, unless there is another `.org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthority` or `org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl` defined somewhere else in your path that doesn't have the same signature.

Comment: double-checked libraries in both wars, they line up perfectly, and no extra copies of libraries.

Comment: I'd propose more in-depth testing then... make a test function that does a getMethod call on the object you're using, and poke around at that to see if you see any weird signatures: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html and the getMethod() or getMethods() methods.

Comment: ok, so it works if I call the mbeanserver.invoke from within the same WAR as the mbean, but I need to call it from a separate WAR.  What could the issue be?

Comment: I'd repeat the process from the other WAR to see if you can get something with a weird signature, but it really sounds like there's an out-of-date class getting loaded somewhere if it works in the WAR but not from outside... could you move the Spring stuff up to EAR level?  That would probably expose you to even more classloader issues, though.

Comment: for now, I worked around it by simply passing strings over the wire, but it should work, right?

Comment: If they're two seperate wars deployed in JBoss, they both load your classes in different classloaders so there will be a class mismatch since the invoker sees the signature of the MBean and the passed arguments as different classes. Benn's proposal to push the wars into a common EAR will work since all deployments inside an EAR have a shared classloader.

Alternatively, put your jar containing these classes into the JBoss server lib. You could fiddle  with JMX and Classloaders but realistically, changing the deployment topology will be easier.

Comment: ah, thanks Nicholas, I suspected something like that but you provided a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes in question can't cross a classloader boundary, it's an argument-type mismatch because the classloader is internally part of the type within jboss.